# About Java input string filter

Tags: java

I have a very simple question about JAVA string filter 
I to want input this command to console.

add 100@10

which means execute add method input arguments 100 and 10 respectively.

I used

```
String[] s = str.split("@");

String a = s[0];// here can get 100

String b=s1];// get can get 10
```

I have two questions

- first is how to do delete the at (@) character before put it to string.split()
- second can anyone can provide some better solution to handle this kind of input ?

such as

```
add 1000@10   //only add,1000,10 need to take 
times 1000@10  //only add,1000,10 need to take
```

Comment: if you remove the @ character, how do you want to split your command?

Comment: you can see my command is add 1000@10,which means 1000+10 i want get the three arguments in the string seperately  ,could be [add][1000][10]

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java

Comment: and apples are not cherries....he posted java code and tagged the question as "Java" - whats the problem

Comment: @messerbill *I* removed the JavaScript tag

Comment: oh ok sorry :D didnt notice

Comment: if you can change input format, why not just have space between each in put, like: add 100 10?  If these are the arguments to the program, then args[0] is the command (add), args[1] is the first value (100), and args[2] is the second value (10)

Comment: so you are running your programm like `java YourClass add 100@10`? If so then just replace that `@` with a space and you'll get a 3 element argument array containing the strings `add`, `100` and `10`.

Answer (score 3):

You can split on multiple tokens because it's a regex parameter:

```
String a[] = "aadd 100@200".split("[ @]");

returns ["aadd", "100", "200"]
```

Then you can do

```
String command = a[0];
String operand1 =  a[1];
String operand2 = a[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

not as sexy as ergonaut's solution, but you also can use two splits:

```
String[] arr1 = "add 100@10".split(" ");
String[] arr2 = arr1[1].split("@");
String[] result = [arr1[0], arr2[0], arr2[1]];
```

should be

```
["add","100","10"]; // this is result
```

greetings